# Moving files according to some pattern with Zsh on MacOS

Tags: macos, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm trying to move files according to some pattern, in the case below, moving all files containing `2018` to `2018/` folder:

```
mv *2018* 2018/
```

This command worked once with `2017`, now then I'm getting

> mv: rename 2018 to 2018/2018: Invalid argument

So I tried `zmv`:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
mv *2018* 2018/
```

It worked, but doesn't work anymore for `2019` or any other value with the same error message.

How should I fix it ? Or what is a better and yet simple way to move files according to some regex pattern ?

*I also have `oh-my-zsh` installed*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
mv *2018*(.) 2018/
```

With the `.` glob qualifier (in the parentheses), the wildcard pattern will only match regular files. Without the qualifier, the source pattern will include the destination directory `2018` in the list of items to move, and `mv` cannot move a directory into itself.

When I tried the original pattern `*2018*` on my system, `mv` still moved the matching files as requested, and then reported the error message about the directory. I suspect that when this appeared to work, the error message was simply lost in some other text.

Demonstrating the `.` glob qualifier:

```
>>>> ls -p1
2017/
2017a.txt
2017b.txt
2018/
2018a.txt
2018b.txt
2019/
2019a.txt
2019b.txt
>>>> print -l *2018*   
2018
2018a.txt
2018b.txt
>>>> print -l *2018*(.)
2018a.txt
2018b.txt
>>>> mv *2018*(.) 2018/
>>>> ls -pR1           
2017/
2017a.txt
2017b.txt
2018/
2019/
2019a.txt
2019b.txt

./2017:

./2018:
2018a.txt
2018b.txt

./2019:
```

---

BTW, the `zmv` example in your question is invoking `mv`, not `zmv`. Also, arguments to `zmv` usually need to be quoted. You don't want `zmv` here, `mv` will do everything needed.